# Remove all commas from single line of text field

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, formula

Trying to remove all commas from a single line of text SharePoint Online field entries.

Any ideas on how to achieve that, any formatting formulas, or JSON?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you trying this? What have you tried so far? What worked, what did not work? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Hi Nils, tried this formula that is meant to be for a single line of text, but didn't work, the commas are still present - =ISNUMBER([ColumnName]+0) . Trying to find any JSON options, but nothing so far. I guess I can do it with jQuery, but then I need to return to classic mode and I want it to work in modern.

Comment: Wouldn't an SPFx extension esp. a `Field Customizer` be what you'd want?

Comment: Don't know what that is?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint JSON formatting now supports `replaceAll` operator which you can use to remove all commas from a single line of text.

Example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent":"=replaceAll(@currentField, ',', '')"
}
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) [FieldCustomizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)

Essentially you then would write

```
@override
public onRenderCell(event: IFieldCustomizerCellEventParameters): void {
  event.domElement.innerHTML = `<div>${event.fieldValue.replace(/[,\.]/g, "")}</div>`;
}
```

or whatever modifications you'd want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Json column formmatting not provide operators to remove/replace special character currently:
[image]

A workaround is to update the single line text field with CSOM Console Application directly to remove commas, please see the same question in the Technet I have replied yesterday:

[Remove all commas from single line of text field](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/17487fa2-8157-49f4-94ee-74d297636dea/remove-all-commas-from-single-line-of-text-field?forum=sharepointdevelopment)